# ImportError: IProgress not found. Please update jupyter and ipywidgets although it is installed

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipywidgets, pandas-profiling

I am using jupyter notebook and installed.

```
ipywidgets==7.4.2 widgetsnbextension pandas-profiling=='.0.0
```

and also I ran:

```
!jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

but when running:

```
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
profile = ProfileReport(df, title="Pandas Profiling Report", explorative=True)
profile.to_widgets()
```

I get the error:

```
ImportError: IProgress not found. Please update jupyter and ipywidgets. See https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html
```

Any idea why?
Tried proposed solutions.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I tried everything you mentioned in a new environment using `conda` and I had another issue related to the version of `ipywidgets` (a bug found in Github with comments saying that got solved after using last version). I solved the problem I had installing last version of `ipywidgets`. Here is my process:

1. Create a new environment using `conda` (I use miniconda):

```
conda create --name teststackoverflow python=3.7
```

2. Activate new environment:

```
conda activate teststackoverflow
```

3. Install `jupyter`:

```
pip install jupyter
```

4. Install all the libraries without specific versions to get the last ones:

```
pip install ipywidgets widgetsnbextension pandas-profiling
```

5. Run `jupyter notebook` in the console to turn on the notebooks server and create a new notebook.
6. Run this line in a new cell:

```
!jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

With the result:

```
Enabling notebook extension jupyter-js-widgets/extension...
      - Validating: OK
```

7. Run some sample code to define `df`:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

8. Run the code you provided:

```py
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
profile = ProfileReport(df, title="Pandas Profiling Report", explorative=True)
profile.to_widgets()
```

Final output looks good:
[image: Final result of running step number 8]

Comment: can u pls elaborate the versions of ipywidgets, widgetsnbextension, pandas-profiling that worked well for you?

Comment: Sure: `ipywidgets==7.6.3`, `pandas-profiling==3.0.0` and `widgetsnbextension==3.5.1`. That's what you expected or do you need more information about how to install them?

Comment: is it possible to export the report to pdf or html?

Comment: Yes, you can do `profile.to_file("your_report.html")`. If you want to download a PDF, just use the print function from the browser to save the HTML into a PDF. You can find more information [here](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling).

Comment: Step 4 was the most important part for me. Thanks!

Comment: Note that pandas-profiling package naming was changed. To continue profiling data use ydata-profiling instead

Answer (score 27):

this had worked for me (for all of you who prefer pip instead of conda..)
in your virtualenv run

```
pip install ipywidgets
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

or, if you prefer to run it in your notebook

```
!pip install ipywidgets
!jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

and in your notebook add

```
from ipywidgets import FloatProgress
```

Comment: I followed this solution but got `AttributeError: 'tqdm_notebook' object has no attribute 'disp'`

Answer (score 4):

Installing ipywidgets and building Jupyter Lab did the trick for me.

0. Make sure you activate the correct conda environment
1. Install ipywidgets: `conda install -c conda-forge ipywidgets`
2. To build Jupyter Lab, you need to have nodejs > 12.0.0 installed. Check the latest version number from [Anaconda website](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/nodejs) and install nodejs specifying the package number e.g. `conda install -c conda-forge nodejs=16.6.1`
3. Stop Jupyter Lab
4. Build Juyter Lab: `jupyter lab build`
5. Start Jupyter Lab

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same error. On M1 mac, I change `from tqdm.notebook import tqdm as tqdm` to `from tqdm import tqdm`. Hope it helps. Original post: https://github.com/CosmiQ/solaris/issues/392#issuecomment-759238485

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same error within the jupyter lab and I just installed ipywidgets using `conda install -c conda-forge ipywidgets` command.

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed in latest update of jupyter. Please run this this command in terminal
`pip install --upgrade jupyter`

Comment: Can you please add a reference to git issues or a git commit record or somewhere indicating that this is the case so that it links to the specific versions and times that this was happening since this original post dates back to 2021?