# VS Code Jupyter Notebook: IProgress not found

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, progress-bar, ipywidgets, tqdm

I'm attempting to run a very simple tqdm script:

```
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(10)):
    time.sleep(1)
```

but am met with:

```
IProgress not found. Please update jupyter and ipywidgets. See https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html
```

My ipywidgets is v8.0.4 and jupyter v1.0.0... does tqdm not work anymore with VS Code Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem. Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67998191/importerror-iprogress-not-found-please-update-jupyter-and-ipywidgets-although) post I resolved it by running:

```py
%pip install --upgrade jupyter ipywidgets
%jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension # removed !pip on the recommendation of a comment.

import time
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(10)):
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Minor thing: When using `pip install` from inside a notebook, you'll have a better experience if you don't use the exclamation point with it, and use the modern magic command added to insure the installation occurs in the environment being used by the kernel underlying the active notebook, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the modern magic commands added to overcome exclamation point shortcomings. You should be suggesting others use that in current Jupyter as well. ...

Comment: <continued>  See [the second paragraph here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez) for a good summary of why the exclamation point use with install commands can lead to issues.

Comment: Thanks @Wayne, I've updated it. I noticed my linter recommending it but I had no idea why.

Comment: I'm not sure the `jupyter nbextension enable` line should be without the exclamation point though? Did you verify that?

Comment: It does somewhat enterprisingly. I checked after I posted to be sure.

Answer (score 6):

This little syntax solved my problem

```
conda install -c conda-forge ipywidgets
```

Remember to restart your kernel after installation. It didn't work until I restarted my VS Code. Hope it helps